# How to rotate a Base64 image by 90 degree without losing image quality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function written in **javascript** that rotates an image by the given input degree using **canvas**

I don't know what to try in order to improve image quality.

In this function given below, I give the first argument as a *base64 image*, the second argument is the degree to which the image should be rotated, the third argument is a callback function.

```
//code for rotating image.
    export const  rotateImage = (imageBase64, rotation, cb) => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageBase64;
    img.onload = () => {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

      canvas.width = img.height;
      canvas.height = img.width;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.translate( Math.floor(img.height/2),Math.floor(img.width/2));

      ctx.rotate(rotation * (Math.PI / 180));

      ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);

      cb(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"))
    };
};
```

**Expected result**: I want the image rotated without losing image quality at all.

**Actual result**: After rotating an image size of 550kb it returns an image of size 80 kb.
the image quality decreases drastically.
how can I rotate this image in such a way that if I rotate a 550kb image by 90 degrees, the quality of the rotated image is 550kb as well?

Thank you for your time.
really appreciate it.

Comment: Using css may be easier and the quality won't change

Comment: Unfortunately jpeg is a lossy format. Just be modifying and resaving the file you are likely to lose quality

Comment: I want to take input as a base64 image and return output as a base 64 image which is rotated by 90 degrees. it is not for viewing in the webpage. but I want the output as a rotated image which does not lose image quality. any suggestions are welcome. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Hai phuzi, is there no way to rotate the image  and save it with the same quality?, or at least higher quality than what I am currently getting? or is there any other approach that I can take to solve this problem? Thank you phuzi.

Comment: There is also solution of adding EXIF data to the image, where you have orientation that will rotate the image. Not useful in every case.

Comment: The calculation made works, basically, only with the rotation of 90 degrees. So it shouldn't be a variable, but a fixed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jpeg is lossy, as a mitigation you could try raising the quality. You might be able to raise the quality and end up with a larger jpeg than before.

According to Mozilla's documentation the default is 0.92
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

I think you should try a quality of 1 and see what you get.

`cb(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1))`

You mention not using the resulting image in a browser. Some uses of JPEG support a tagged orientation. I can't recommend any tools to try, but take a look at https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html

`ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);` Are you sure this line isn't resizing the image to half of its size?

Comment: I am trying to rotate a rectangular image, hence that line. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Set the quality parameter to 1.

```
cb(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1));
```

Also, I would go for PNG since it is a lossless file format.

```
cb(canvas.toDataURL("image/png",1));
```

Comment: Thank you, grizlizli. image quality is coming out good and when I change the format, the image size increased as well.

Comment: No problem. :) 
Have a good one. 

P.S. Approve the answer if that's fine by you. @Harry

Comment: Or just don't pass anything, as PNG is the default value. canvas.toDataURL()